# How to get physical files from git stash repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I am using Atlassian Stash as a git repository management system.

I have a 2 branchs 1 master and 1 for production . I am installing atlasian stash in a separate server I have two ideas for the remote server to be synced with the repo .The first is to move the files from the master branch to that server or make the server map to the folder that contains the files but i can't find the physical files in the master branch .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "map the production server to them"?

Comment: I mean that production server will be directed to the physical files .

Comment: What branch should be used? How wold you control that? Typically a "consumer" would simply clone the required repo. Please elaborate what scenario you are thinking of. Thanks

Comment: Ok I have a 2 branchs 1 master and 1 for production . I am installing atlasian stash in a separate  server  i have two ideas for the remote server to be synced with the repo .The first is to move  the files from the master branch to that  server or make the server map to the folder that contains the files but i can't find the physical files in the master branch .

Comment: Lets say you just clone that production branch on that separate server using the git command line client and don't install stash again. This gives you the files... Where is this approach insufficient?

Comment: If @reto's comment is insufficient, I think you need to explain your *high-level* goals more clearly before we can help you.

Comment: @reto Yes but I need some sort of automated process that clone the project from master branch to  live server .  Stash is a must for the team to contribute to the project .

Comment: But you only need one stash instance for the team to collaborate. You don't need a 2nd instance running on the live server. There are various ways to automate git pulls (on commit, using cron, etc.) google these.

Comment: my main issue is that when we installed stash the default setting for storing files is in database so we can't see physical files I need to know to change stash setting back to normal files

Answer (score 1):

You should do a standard `git clone` on the production server. If you want to keep the production server in sync with a specific branch, you probably want to use a [repository hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+repository+hooks).

For example, you could set up a [web post receive hook](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.stash.plugin.stash-web-post-receive-hooks-plugin) that sends a POST to somewhere on your production server. When your production server receives the POST (for which you would have to write some code), it would execute a script that performs a `git pull`.

If you want a more nuanced approach (eg. only update production when certain things happen) then you can change your script accordingly.

Comment: my main issue is that when we installed stash the default setting for storing files is in database so we can't see physical files I need to know to change stash setting back to normal files

Comment: But why do you need access to the physical files? I thought your wrote that your high-level goal was just to clone the project from the master branch to the live server?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to change stash default way of storing repo files in db to normal physical files or not and how just for the sake of knowledge

Comment: As far as I know, Stash always stores repos in the filesystem. What makes you believe that it is storing them in the database?

Comment: because i have searched for the folder directory and i couldn't found it

Comment: You mean it's not here? https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/114211/answers/4033310 (ie. Under $STASH_HOME/data/repositories?)

Comment: Hi Ahmad, as Scott suggested, the files are in the filesystem, but they're stored as bare repos. That is not really important though, as this is absolutely the wrong way to access your repos under pretty much any circumstance. git commands are the way to go.